# "compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle.", although I have "compileSdk"

Tags: android, gradle

I have in app level `build.gradle` this, why gradle doesn't recognize shorter version of `compileSdkVersion`?

```
android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "androidx.car.app.sample.helloworld"
        minSdkVersion 29
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // Enables code shrinking, obfuscation, and optimization.
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
                    'proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    namespace "androidx.car.app.sample.helloworld"
}
```

Comment: What version of the plugin are you using?  the newest is 7.2.2

Comment: Hello! Try to change compileSdk to compileSdkVersion

Comment: Indeed, it was to do with gradle version. I updated, and the issue is resolved, thank you @L.Swifter